# How to have current page's link a different color?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, user-experience

I have a navigation menu and I want the link to the page that the user is currently on to be a different color. I thought I could use a:active (or a:focus) but they just flash the different color and when the new page loads, it has the default color.

I am using Wordpress but after doing a simple experiemnnt, I still am suprised by the results.

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>css link test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
This is a test.<br />
<a href="page1.html">page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html">page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>css link test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
This is another page.<br />
<a href="page1.html">page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html">page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
a:active {
     color: rgb(0,128,0);
}
```

How can I make it so that if page2.html is loaded, the link for it will be green? By the way, from a user experience perspective I had a hard time decided what the color actually should be for the active link, is there any literature on the subject?

Comment: active is only for when the link is being clicked, you need to add a class that denotes you are on a certain page and style that.  This might help you out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209175/adding-custom-current-menu-item-class-to-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a different class for the active link. Then in CSS create a class with such different styles. For example:

Page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<head>
    <title>css link test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
   This is a test.<br />
   <a href="page1.html" class="active_page">page 1</a>
   <a href="page2.html">page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
.active_page{
     color: rgb(0,128,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Than you need to make the li active, on the server side. So when you are drawing the menu, you should know which page is loaded and set it to:

```
.menu li:hover, .menu li.active {
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li class="active">Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li> 
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());

  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function (index)
  {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
)

//Add the clicked button class
 $(this).addClass('active');
}

//Attach events to menu
$(document).ready(
 function()
 {
   $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
 }  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hntuf/23/)**

```js
var make_button_active = function()
{
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());
  siblings.each(function (index)
  {
    $(this).removeClass('active-page');
  }
)
 $(this).addClass('active-page');
}
$(document).ready(
 function()
 {
   $("a").click(make_button_active);
 }  
)
```

```css
.a:hover, a.active-page {
   color: rgb(0,128,0);;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>css link test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    This is a test.<br />
    <a class="active-page" href="#">page 1</a>
    <a href="#">page 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```